# How do I redirect any subdomain through htaccess as GET parameter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wildcard-subdomain

So if the user enters london.abcd.com, it needs to go to abcs.com/show.php?loc=london while still showing the URL london.abcd.com

Another example: 
(Enters) sydney.abcd.com -> (goes to) abcd.com/show.php?loc=sydney and the URL shows sydney.abcd.com

How do I achieve this via HTACCESS both for localhost(XAMPP on Windows) and the actual server online?

Tried this so far but doesn't work. Redirects me back to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%2.com/show.php?loc=%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a working variant of what you suggest. Note however that it will *ignore* any path specified within the requested URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exmaple\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/show.php?loc=%1 [R=301,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In your comment to this answer you point out that you actually do *not* want a redirect, as written in the question, but an internal rewrite. So the visible URL in the browser should not be altered, only the internal processing should be. This is possible with a slight modification:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exmaple\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /show.php?loc=%1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for such an elaborated response.
While this works, after the redirection the URL shows as https://example.com/show.php?loc=sydney. But I want it to show htttps://sydney.example.com even after the redirection. How do I achieve that?

Comment: So unlike what you wrote in your question you do _not_ want a redirect, but instead an internal rewrite. I added that option to the answer.

Comment: Sorry for mixing up the terms and creating confusion.

Comment: @UneditedReality All fine, as long as I can help :-)